# Threshold limit on a Quantum DXi 4000 series

Tags: backup

I have a very specific question. It is my first question here so I hope to be doing it correctly.

I have a Quantum DXi 4510i that a client is using for the backup solution. This appliance is interesting because do deduplication of data. The problem is that when the disk gets to a threshold limit (550GB of free space at disk) enter into a throttle mode and the data ingest is being done veeery slowly (around 100k/s) the regular speeds are around 70MB/s!!

There are tw obvious solutions from my point of view:

1) Increasing the disk space
2) Deleting some old backups

The problem with the first option is that it will take a looot of time to be done by the support so meanwhile we need a workaround solution. This workaround solution is deleting some backups. But this is taking a lot of time because before of deleting old backups they need a confirmation from the HQ. Meanwhile they have no real backup of their servers...

That is the current situation and I have think of another solution that is changing the threshold limit but I cannot find the option in the configurations menu. But googling I read it is possible to change the threshold value from 5% to 95% this would be great in order to have backups a few more days till the OK from the HQ arrives.

Sorry for the long message, thank you all by your time!!

Comment: This is very specific, I suggest calling their support line.

Comment: Does DXi4000 provide file level access to the backups? If true you could just move the old backups away from the appliance.

Comment: It is very specific and we already have an open case with the support line but I can't believe it how slow are they replying. I don't know for the rest of the people but for me backup is a key point!

Comment: And yes Dimitri we can access directly the data but they are deduplicated so they are around 35TB and we don't have in the client that amount of disk. I think the main problem here is that nobody in the client side is taking seriously the problem :S

Anyway thanks for your help, let's see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Quantum you cannot change that so the only solution was to upgrade it with more hard drives or delete old backups (we did that one).

Comment: interesting... good to know that you still need X amount of scratch space to land a job